# prioritizing a member of a structure array using bubble sort c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am trying to write a function that prioritizes an array of a structure orders. Orders must be prioritized by the earliest date however if orders have the same date they must be prioritized by the largest cost of item.

I have already sorted the array by date using three functions that bubble sort the year, month and day. I thought I could just bubble sort the cost of items of orders under the condition that date of an order and the date of an order before are equal. The function does not sort the list completely and I can't seem to understand why... a little help would be appreciated.

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


struct Date{
int day;
int month;
int year;
};

struct SizeOfBox{
int length;
int width;
int height;
};

struct PriceOfItem{
int dollars;
int cents;
};

struct Shipment {
string foodName;
Date expdate;
SizeOfBox sizeofbox;
float weightOfBox;
char storageMethod;
Date shipmentrecieved;
PriceOfItem priceofitem;
};

struct Customers{
string customerName;
string city;
int distance;
};

struct Orders{
string customerName;
string itemName;
int numberOfBoxes;
PriceOfItem costofitem;
Date orderDate;

};

const int NO_OF_SHIPMENTS = 100;

Shipment shipments[NO_OF_SHIPMENTS];

void getDataOrders(ifstream& inFile);
void displayOrders(Orders orders[],int totalOrders);


void sortYear (Orders orders[],int totalOrders);
void sortMonth (Orders orders[],int totalOrders);
void sortDay (Orders orders[],int totalOrders);
void priority (Orders orders[],int totalOrders);
void creatOutFile(char inName[],string& outName);


int main()
{
ifstream inDataOrders;
ofstream out;

inDataOrders.open("Orders.txt");

if (!inDataOrders)
{
    cout << "The Orders input file does not exist. Program terminates!"                 <<endl;   
    return 1;
}

 out.open("Priority Orders.txt");
 getDataOrders(inDataOrders);


return 0;
}

void getDataOrders(ifstream& inFile){
char decimal;
int totalOrderItems;

    inFile >> totalOrderItems;     /// the length of the list is on the
                                  /// first line in the text file being read
Orders orders[totalOrderItems];

for(int i = 0; i < totalOrderItems; i++){
    inFile >> orders[i].customerName;
    inFile >> orders[i].itemName;
    inFile >> orders[i].numberOfBoxes;
    inFile >> orders[i].costofitem.dollars >> decimal >> orders[i].costofitem.cents;
    inFile >> orders[i].orderDate.month >> decimal >> orders[i].orderDate.day >> decimal >> orders[i].orderDate.year;
}

inFile.close();

sortYear(orders, totalOrderItems);
sortMonth(orders,totalOrderItems);
sortDay(orders,totalOrderItems);


priority(orders,totalOrderItems);


displayOrders(orders, totalOrderItems);

 }

 void displayOrders(Orders orders[],int totalOrders)
 {

cout << setw(10) << setfill(' ') << "Customer Name" << " | "
     << "Item Name" << "  | "
     << "#Boxes" << "  | "
     << "Cost" << "  | "
     << "Order Date" << "\n"<< endl;

for(int i = 0; i < totalOrders; i++){
    cout << left << setw(10) << orders[i].customerName << "    | "
         << left << setw(10) << orders[i].itemName << " | "
         << right << setw(2) << setfill('0') << orders[i].numberOfBoxes << "      | "
         << right << setw(2) << setfill('0') << orders[i].costofitem.dollars <<"." << setw(2) << setfill('0') << orders[i].costofitem.cents << " | "
         << right << setw(2) << setfill('0') << orders[i].orderDate.month <<":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << orders[i].orderDate.day <<":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << orders[i].orderDate.year << " "
         << setfill(' ') << endl;
  }
}


void sortYear (Orders orders[],int totalOrders)
{
int p, w;

for (p=0; p<totalOrders; p++)
{
    for (w=1; w<= totalOrders-1; w++)

       if (orders[w-1].orderDate.year > orders[w].orderDate.year)
            {
                swap(orders[w-1].customerName, orders[w].customerName);
                swap(orders[w-1].itemName, orders[w].itemName);
                swap(orders[w-1].numberOfBoxes, orders[w].numberOfBoxes);
                swap(orders[w-1].costofitem.dollars,       orders[w].costofitem.dollars);
                swap(orders[w-1].costofitem.cents, orders[w].costofitem.cents);
                swap(orders[w-1].orderDate.month, orders[w].orderDate.month);
                swap(orders[w-1].orderDate.day, orders[w].orderDate.day);
                swap(orders[w-1].orderDate.year, orders[w].orderDate.year);
            }

   }
 }

void sortMonth (Orders orders[],int totalOrders)
{
  int p, w;

for (p=0; p<totalOrders; p++)
{
    for (w=1; w<= totalOrders-1; w++)

    if (orders[w].orderDate.year == orders[w-1].orderDate.year)


       if (orders[w-1].orderDate.month > orders[w].orderDate.month)
            {
                swap(orders[w-1].customerName, orders[w].customerName);
                swap(orders[w-1].itemName, orders[w].itemName);
                swap(orders[w-1].numberOfBoxes, orders[w].numberOfBoxes);
                swap(orders[w-1].costofitem.dollars, orders[w].costofitem.dollars);
                swap(orders[w-1].costofitem.cents, orders[w].costofitem.cents);
                swap(orders[w-1].orderDate.month, orders[w].orderDate.month);
                swap(orders[w-1].orderDate.day, orders[w].orderDate.day);
                swap(orders[w-1].orderDate.year, orders[w].orderDate.year);
            }

    }
 }

 void sortDay (Orders orders[],int totalOrders)
 {
      int p, w;

 for (p=0; p<totalOrders; p++)
 {
    for (w=1; w<= totalOrders-1; w++)

    if (orders[w].orderDate.month == orders[w-1].orderDate.month)

       if (orders[w-1].orderDate.day > orders[w].orderDate.day)
            {
                swap(orders[w-1].customerName, orders[w].customerName);
                swap(orders[w-1].itemName, orders[w].itemName);
                swap(orders[w-1].numberOfBoxes, orders[w].numberOfBoxes);
                swap(orders[w-1].costofitem.dollars, orders[w].costofitem.dollars);
                swap(orders[w-1].costofitem.cents, orders[w].costofitem.cents);
                swap(orders[w-1].orderDate.month, orders[w].orderDate.month);
                swap(orders[w-1].orderDate.day, orders[w].orderDate.day);
                swap(orders[w-1].orderDate.year, orders[w].orderDate.year);
            }

     }

  }

   void priority (Orders orders[],int totalOrders)
   {

   for (int p=0; p<totalOrders; p++)
   {
    for (int x=0;x<totalOrders-1;x++)
    {
    if  ((orders[x+1].orderDate.year == orders[x].orderDate.year) &&
        (orders[x+1].orderDate.month == orders[x].orderDate.month) &&
        (orders[x+1].orderDate.day == orders[x].orderDate.day) &&
        (orders[x+1].costofitem.dollars >= orders[x].costofitem.dollars) &&
        (orders[x+1].costofitem.cents > orders[x].costofitem.cents))
            {
                swap(orders[x+1].customerName, orders[x].customerName);
                swap(orders[x+1].itemName, orders[x].itemName);
                swap(orders[x+1].numberOfBoxes, orders[x].numberOfBoxes);
                swap(orders[x+1].costofitem.dollars, orders[x].costofitem.dollars);
                swap(orders[x+1].costofitem.cents, orders[x].costofitem.cents);
                swap(orders[x+1].orderDate.month, orders[x].orderDate.month);
                swap(orders[x+1].orderDate.day, orders[x].orderDate.day);
                swap(orders[x+1].orderDate.year, orders[x].orderDate.year);

            }
           cout << x+1 << " is swapped with " <<x<< endl;
    }
    cout << p << " outside loop " << endl;
  }
```

It seems to swap some orders correctly but not swap others, in other words the highest cost should bubble to the top for every identical date, but it is not.

here is a sample of before and after using the function void priority :

Before :

Customer Name | Item Name  | #Boxes  | Cost  | Order Date

Sajan         | Oranges    | 20      | 87.00 | 10:12:2014

Jay           | Carrot     | 08      | 90.09 | 10:12:2014

Pepp          | Bananas    | 05      | 10.10 | 10:12:2014

Smith         | Apples     | 02      | 80.00 | 10:12:2014

Smith         | PineApple  | 07      | 50.20 | 10:12:2014

Finn          | PineApple  | 08      | 55.55 | 10:12:2014

Charlie       | Apples     | 07      | 20.85 | 10:12:2014

Rishi         | Potato     | 02      | 29.99 | 10:12:2014

Gracy         | Grapes     | 09      | 47.74 | 10:12:2014

Bruce         | Bananas    | 05      | 32.20 | 10:12:2014

Rishi         | Tomato     | 03      | 34.43 | 12:13:2014

Rishi         | Kiwi       | 10      | 88.99 | 12:13:2014

Pepp          | Chicken    | 18      | 14.30 | 12:13:2014

Sajan         | Potato     | 15      | 99.90 | 12:13:2014

John          | Grapes     | 09      | 78.78 | 12:13:2014

Sajan         | PineApple  | 07      | 25.45 | 12:13:2014

Vijay         | Kiwi       | 10      | 88.98 | 12:25:2014

Pepp          | Chicken    | 13      | 94.92 | 12:25:2014

---

After:

Customer Name | Item Name  | #Boxes  | Cost  | Order Date

Jay           | Carrot     | 08      | 90.09 | 10:12:2014

Sajan         | Oranges    | 20      | 87.00 | 10:12:2014

Pepp          | Bananas    | 05      | 10.10 | 10:12:2014

Smith         | Apples     | 02      | 80.00 | 10:12:2014

Finn          | PineApple  | 08      | 55.55 | 10:12:2014

Smith         | PineApple  | 07      | 50.20 | 10:12:2014

Rishi         | Potato     | 02      | 29.99 | 10:12:2014

Charlie       | Apples     | 07      | 20.85 | 10:12:2014

Gracy         | Grapes     | 09      | 47.74 | 10:12:2014

Bruce         | Bananas    | 05      | 32.20 | 10:12:2014

Rishi         | Kiwi       | 10      | 88.99 | 12:13:2014

Sajan         | Potato     | 15      | 99.90 | 12:13:2014

John          | Grapes     | 09      | 78.78 | 12:13:2014

---

edit

```
bool lessThan ( Orders orders[],int x)
{


if (orders[x-1].costofitem.dollars < orders[x].costofitem.dollars)
    return true;
else if (orders[x-1].costofitem.dollars == orders[x].costofitem.dollars)
    return orders[x-1].costofitem.cents < orders[x].costofitem.cents;
return false;
}

void priority (Orders orders[],int totalOrders)
   {

   for (int p=0; p<totalOrders; p++)
   {
    for (int x=0;x<totalOrders-1;x++)
    {
    if  ((orders[x+1].orderDate.year == orders[x].orderDate.year) &&
        (orders[x+1].orderDate.month == orders[x].orderDate.month) &&
        (orders[x+1].orderDate.day == orders[x].orderDate.day) &&
        (lessThan(orders,x))
            {
                swap(orders[x+1].customerName, orders[x].customerName);
                swap(orders[x+1].itemName, orders[x].itemName);
                swap(orders[x+1].numberOfBoxes, orders[x].numberOfBoxes);
                swap(orders[x+1].costofitem.dollars, orders[x].costofitem.dollars);
                swap(orders[x+1].costofitem.cents, orders[x].costofitem.cents);
                swap(orders[x+1].orderDate.month, orders[x].orderDate.month);
                swap(orders[x+1].orderDate.day, orders[x].orderDate.day);
                swap(orders[x+1].orderDate.year, orders[x].orderDate.year);

            }

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to sorting the list several times, for each element separately. A more common solution to you problem is to compare elements pairwise by the particular ordering you want. Writing your own sorting functions is unnecessary when STL can do the job for you much more efficiently. You can sort the structures using std::sort and a lambda function (if your compiler supports C++11)

```
std::sort(shipments, shipments+NO_OF_SHIPMENTS, [] (const Shipment &s1,  const    Shipment &s2)
{
     return s1.expdate.year  != s2.expdate.year ?  s1.expdate.year  < s2.expdate.year :
           s1.expdate.month  != s2.expdate.month ?  s1.expdate.month < s2.expdate.month :
           s1.expdate.day  != s2.expdate.day ?  s1.expdate.day < s2.expdate.day :
           s1.priceOfItem.dollar*100+s1.priceOfItem.cents < s2.priceOfItem.dollar*100+s2.priceOfItem.cents;
 });
```

If your compiler doesn't support C++11, you can override Shipment's operator < in a similar fashion.

Comment: The problem was the comparison between the costofItem in the priority function.  I fixed this buy writing a separate function that compares money and using that Boolean value as a condition.

Comment: I can understand  now the intention of you code - sort by year, then inside each year by month etc. Though it works, it is writing a large amount of code for something that can be written in several lines. This is error prone, as the longer the code, the more chances of bugs. In addition, It's not efficient. and it's much harder for others to read. I recommend that you learn how to use STL it will make your coding easier, happier and better.